# Traverse all numbers with only one bit flip per step

Tags: code-golf, number

You can count 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.
But to get from 3 to 4 you have to change 3 bits at once.
Given a number of bits, how can you go through all numbers once,
but change at each step only 1! bit.

Here is an example for 3 bits:

```
000 100 110 010 011 111 101 001
```

so the output is:

```
0 1 3 2 6 7 5 4
```

### Rules:

- given a number of bits n, return a list of 2^n unique numbers
- between to consecutive numbers only one bit is different
- the shorter the code the better

Comment: This is fundamentally the same question as http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4094 with a different winning criterion.

Answer (score 5):

Python 3:

```
for i in range(2**n):i^i//2
```

(Doh. Overlooked that this solutions is already known. Would delete it if stackexchange allowed it)

Answer (score 2):

### GolfScript, 13 chars

```
~2\?,{.2/^}%`
```

For example, the input `3` produces the output `[0 1 3 2 6 7 5 4]`.

Here's a de-golfed version with comments:

```
~              # evaluate the input, turning it from a string into a number
2 \ ?          # raise 2 to the power given by the input...
,              # ...and turn it into a list containing the numbers from 0 to 2^n-1
{ . 2 / ^ } %  # xor each number in the list with itself divided by 2
`              # un-eval the list into a string for output
```

It's perhaps interesting to note that there are no particular "golfing tricks" involved — this *is* basically the most obvious and straightforward way to solve this task in GolfScript.

Answer (score 1):

### C++, 188 bytes

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#define y if(b)f(b-1)
int x=0;
void f(int b){y;std::cout<<(x^=1<<b)<<' ';y;}
int main(int,char**v){int b=std::atoi(v[1]);std::cout<<x<<' ';y;}
```

Specify the number of bits on the command line and it will print a list of space separated integers.

Answer (score 0):

## F# (32)

```
[for i in 0..(1<<<n)-1->i^^^i/2]
```

If explicit output is not required, this will do the job (45 chars):

```
for i in 0..(1<<<n)-1 do printf"%i "(i^^^i/2)
```

<sup>Disclaimer: Very similar to the answer I provided [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32893/7548), just simplified to fit the output specified here.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
2*Ḷ^H$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@2@k9XDHtjgPlf///xsDAA)

#### How it works

```
2*Ḷ^H$  Main link. Argument: n

2*      Yield 2ⁿ.
  Ḷ     Unlength; yield [0, ..., 2ⁿ].
     $  Combine the two links to the left into a chain.
   ^H       XOR each k in the range with k/2.
```